# Macros behaving differently in C and gives different output

Tags: c, macros

Iam new to c. Here defined a macro as `#define val 4+2`. when try to print square using `val*val` it gives output as `14` instead of `36`. How is this happening, but when macro is defined as `#define val 6` it gives correct output. Here is the sample code snippet. Can someone explain why is this so?

```
#define max 4+2

int main()
{
   printf("%d\n",max);    
   int i = max*max;
   printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

output:
6
14

Comment: `4+2*4+2` and `(4+2)*(4+2)` have different values ... or in other words: use parenthesis in your macros: `#define max (4+2)`

Comment: you cant use enough parentheses when it comes to C macros

Comment: ... except for, for instance, (`17246`and `55189`) or (`75313` and `76036`) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
int i = max*max;
```

expands to

```
int i = 4 + 2 * 4 + 2;
```

which is equivalent to

```
int i = 4 + (2 * 4) + 2;
```

If you want the result to be

```
int i = (4 + 2) * (4 + 2);
```

then you need to explicitly add the parentheses in the macro:

```
#define max (4+2)
```

---

This is a common "flaw" with macros, and one reason their usage is discouraged, or to be used for very simple constant values only.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are "stupid" text replacement, with no semantic understanding. If you replace "max" with "4+2" (which is what the preprocessor does), you'll see the initialization of `i` is resolved as:

```c
int i = 4+2*4+2;
```

From here, it's easier to see that the result is 4+2*4+2=4+8+2=14.

If you want `max` to represent 6 "the hard way", you could surround it with parentheses:

```c
#define max (4+2)
```

This way, the preprocessor will resolve:

```c
int i = (4+2)*(4+2);
```

And you'll get i=36 as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code through pre-processor (`gcc -E`)

```
//removing the content from stdio.h for brevity...

int main()
{
   printf("%d\n",4+2);   // output : 6, as expected
   int i = 4+2*4+2;      // note the expansion here, not what you'd expect!
   printf("%d\n",i);     // value of 'i' is not what you'd expect!
}
```

So, to elaborate a statement like

```
 int i = 4+2*4+2;
```

is effectively the same as

```
int i = (4) + (2*4) + (2) ;
```

which produces the output of `14`, not `36`, as for the lack of parenthesis-enforced operator precedence, default precedence is at work and it's executed as shown above.

**Suggestion:** Always wrap your macros in parenthesis to avoid this.